# Equivalent of reinterpret Node.js fii in C++

Tags: c++, node.js, tensorflow

I am trying to replicate [this](https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-tensorflow-graphs-via-host-languages-be10fd81876f#.xhgxjwjqb) example in C++ and I am stuck at the absolute final step to read the data.

```
exports.TF_ReadTensorData = function(tensor, size, type) {
  var ptr = libtensorflow.TF_TensorData(tensor);
  ptr = ptr.reinterpret(size, 0);
  ptr.type = type;
  return ptr.deref();
}
```

For C++ I have done this so far.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "tf_session_helper.h"
#include "tf_session_helper.cc"
#include "tf_tensor_helper.cc"
#include "tensorflow/core/public/tensor_c_api.h"
using namespace std;

main()
{ 
    TF_DataType::TF_UINT16;
    auto status     = TF_NewStatus();
    auto status_ops = TF_NewSessionOptions();
    auto session    = TF_NewSession(status_ops, status);
    std::ifstream in("graph.pb");
    std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), 
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    TF_ExtendGraph(session,contents.c_str(),contents.length(),status);
    long long adims[] ={};
    float aData[] ={3};
    auto aTensor = tensorflow::TF_NewTensor_wrapper(TF_DataType::TF_FLOAT,adims,0,aData,(sizeof(aData)/sizeof(*aData)));
    long long bdims[] ={};
    float bData[] ={2};
    auto bTensor = tensorflow::TF_NewTensor_wrapper(TF_DataType::TF_FLOAT,bdims,0,bData,(sizeof(bData)/sizeof(*bData)));
    vector<std::string> input_names;
    input_names.push_back("a"); 
    input_names.push_back("b"); 
    vector<std::string> output_names;
    output_names.push_back("c"); 
    vector<std::string> target_names;
    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(aTensor);inputs.push_back(bTensor);
    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> output;

    tensorflow::TF_Run_wrapper(session,input_names,inputs,output_names,output,target_names,status);
    cout << (TF_GetCode(status) == TF_Code::TF_OK) << "\n";
    auto c = output[0];
    auto type = TF_TensorType(c);
    auto dims = TF_NumDims(c);
    auto size = TF_TensorByteSize(c);
    auto readed = TF_TensorData(c);
    cout << type << " " << dims  << " " << size << " " << "\n";

}
```

I am not really an expert in C++ and I would like to know how to replicate ptr = ptr.reinterpret(size, 0) in C++. 
Also I am using a shared library to compile this.

Comment: Perhaps, this is what you want? http://devdocs.io/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to access the data in `readed = TF_TensorData(c)`. The way you handle this depends on the element type in tensor `c`.  Assuming it is a simple type (like `float`, `double`, or `int32`, but not `string`), you can simply cast the data to an array of that type. For example, assuming `c` is a `float` tensor:

```
float* tensor_data = static_cast<float*>(TF_TensorData(c));

int64 total_elements = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < dims; ++i) {
    total_elements *= TF_Dim(c, i);
}

// Print every element of the tensor:
for (int i = 0; i < total_elements; ++i) {
    cout << tensor_data[i];
}
```

The TensorFlow codebase contains examples of using `TF_TensorData()` to access tensor contents in [`tf_session_helper.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b3cdbcf13659b8a6bfe83b61248ab0e429fd9273/tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc). However, note that these examples are intertwined with use of the Python C API, so they aren't the most readable code.

You may find it easier to use the TensorFlow C++ API, rather than the C API. The file [`example_trainer.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b3cdbcf13659b8a6bfe83b61248ab0e429fd9273/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc) shows how to use the [`tensorflow::Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/cc/ClassSession.html#class-tensorflow-session) class to run TensorFlow graphs and retrieve results as [`tensorflow::Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/cc/ClassTensor.html#class-tensorflow-tensor) objects, which are easier to manipulate.

Comment: I have another question as a follow up to this about c API. Can you please give an example for how to make a tensor with string data type. I have seen an example in Go API for this [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/go/tensorflow/contrib/go/tensor.go#L201). But I am not sure how to do it,in C++.